# Probability of 2 of three independent events occuring

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Three objects are thrown at a target.  The probabilities the individual objects will connect with the target is .75, .85 and .90.  Find the probability that at LEAST two of the objects hit the target?  I am having trouble getting this one started...Does anyone have any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Find the following probabilities:
1) All 3 hit the target
2) 1st two hit the target and 3rd misses.
3) 1st and 3rd hit the target and 2nd misses
4) 2nd and 3rd hit the target and 1st misses

Then add them all up to get your answer.

Comment: and the probability of all three hitting would be .75*.85*.95 since they are all independent events...Is my understanding correct

Comment: @Brian: Yes- that's right.